# Random number in mysql

Tags: php, sql

I have a mysql table of inscriptions to a collage signatures. The table has the document of the student repeated depending of the amount of signatures that he want to course.
I want to assign to every student a random number so I use this:

```
SET @rnd := 0;
UPDATE `productData` SET `randCol`= (@rnd := @rnd + 1)
ORDER BY RAND();
```

but as the "document number" (document field) is repeated so I end up giving different random numbers to the same person (the same document number)

the result was this:

```
randomNum-document-field1-field2-field3-field4-field5
    190-1780859-75-1035-CURRICULAR-0-3
    91-1780859-75-1954-OPTATIVA-25-0
    7154-1780859-75-1025-CURRICULAR-0-3
    6424-1780859-75-1910-OPTATIVA-LIBRE-0
    3561-1780859-75-1948-OPTATIVA-60-0
    6028-1780859-75-2105P-CURRICULAR-0-4
    4936-1780859-75-2100P-CURRICULAR-0-4
    6787-1780859-75-2095-CURRICULAR-0-3
    4392-1780859-75-4170-CURRICULAR-0-3
    1858-1780859-75-1932-OPTATIVA-30-0
    3350-1780859-75-3140-CURRICULAR-0-4
    3974-1780859-75-2190-CURRICULAR-0-4
    2676-1780859-75-2115P-CURRICULAR-0-4
    1527-1921177-93-2115P-CURRICULAR-0-4
    6822-1921177-93-2095-CURRICULAR-0-3
    540-1921177-93-2105P-CURRICULAR-0-4
    3770-1921177-93-2100P-CURRICULAR-0-4
    3128-2020703-269-3140-CURRICULAR-0-4
    4386-2020703-269-4160-CURRICULAR-0-3
    5328-2762533-249-3020P-CURRICULAR-0-28
    6356-2971526-355-1954-OPTATIVA-25-0
    1287-3102055-55-1021-CURRICULAR-0-25
    1699-3102055-55-2095-CURRICULAR-0-3
    4759-3102055-55-2190-CURRICULAR-0-4
    4420-3102055-55-3140-CURRICULAR-0-4
    695-3584576-153-4160-CURRICULAR-0-3
```

but i want the same random number to the same document. Let say the random number "190" should be assign to the "1780859" document and so on...

Any help will be very welcome...

Thank you very much for your time...

Comment: If using PHP then just `$rand = rand();` and then use `$rand` in the query.  Or maybe store a random number in the table with the students for each student and use that for all of their documents.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use `join` and precalculate the value per `document`:

```
UPDATE productData pd
       (SELECT document, row_number() over (order by rand()) as seqnum
        FROM productdata
        group by document
       ) d
       ON pd.document = d.document
    SET pd.randCol = d.seqnum;
```